# Assign a class to the variable and use latest as the Type. Is not possbile?

Tags: typescript

Consider this example

```
class Foo { }
const Baz = Foo;

function getBaz(): Baz {
    return new Baz();
}

var baz: Baz = new Baz();
```

Both `Baz` annotations throw errors:

> Cannot find name 'Baz'.

Is it possible to use the `Baz` variable from example as a type?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type system doesn't see `Baz` as a type name, only as a variable name.  If you want to use `Baz` as a type name, you need to do this:

```
class Foo { }
const Baz = Foo;
type Baz = Foo; // tell the type system

function getBaz(): Baz {
    return new Baz();
}

var baz: Baz = new Baz();
```

Hope that is sufficient.  Cheers.

Comment: Yes, thank you, it looks like, this additional `Baz` type declaration is required.